# Angular 2 Architecture, Place for services

Tags: angular, service, architecture, angular-services

I am creating new project in Angular 2. For folder structure i am following Heroes sample app. 
1. In Heroes app, Services are placed inside domain folder. 
2. In my project my services are shared between several components, It can be referred from several domain folders.
3. I am thinking creating each domain as module. but only other than Services and Model [DTO]. Services can be go under one module naming as serviceModule.
Same way for Model named as businessObjects.

I am crating separate module for services and business objects so that i can create module out of it and use it. Rather than domain module.
I am not sure will it cause any performance issue.[in terms of Memory, Speed]

It would be great if you give me few open source projects which i can refer for architecture.